# Catch clearly defined exception from sub.submodule in python

Tags: python, exception

I have 3 files. xxx which imports xxx2 and xxx2 imports xxx3 which one raises OppsError exception.

**xxx3.py:**

```
class OppsError(Exception):pass

def go():
    raise OppsError()
```

**xxx2.py:**

```
import xxx3
xxx3.go()
```

**xxx.py:**

```
try:
    import xxx2
except xxx3.OppsError:
    print 'ops'
```

When i run xxx.py i get error `NameError: name 'xxx3' is not defined`. Is importing xxx3 inside xxx only way to catch `OppsError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is (unless you are willing to replace `OppsError` with a built-in exception that is already known to `xxx` or to catch a more general exception instead of `OppsError` from which `OppsError` is derived).